# error when run and debug cmake project in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

i have problem with vscode
i create simple C++ project with shared library. in the source i separated the app and the library. the code using cmake. the project build fine . but when i want to run or debug it get error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DA1OC.png)

and the intelisense also error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPcwG.png)

when i run without the vscode and copy the dll library it runs fine.
what should i do to able to run and debug it. need help. and thanks

Comment: On Stack Overflow we expect **code** and the **error message** to be in the **question post** itself, not linked as images. Please, (re-)read [ask] and update the question post accordingly.

Comment: I would suggest posting your CMakeLists.txt and your code as @Tsyvarev mentioned. From what I saw from your pictures though the problem seems to be with your include directories.